# how does a server execute different tasks based on client input?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, server

I am currently implementing a socket server using Python's socketServer module. I am struggling to understand how a client 'signals' the server to perform certain tasks.

As you can tell, I am a beginner in this area. I have looked at many tutorials, however, these only tell you how to perform singular tasks in the server e.g. modify a message from the client and send it back.

Ideally what I want to know is there a way for the client to communicate with the server to perform different kinds of tasks.

Is there a standard approach to this issue?

Am I even using the correct type of server?

I was thinking of implementing some form of message passing from the client that tells the server which task it should perform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was thinking of implementing some form of message passing from the client that tells the server which task it should perform.

That's exactly what you need: an application protocol.

A socket (assuming a streaming Internet socket, or TCP) is a stream of bytes, nothing more. To give those bytes any meaning, you need a protocol that determines which byte (or sequence thereof) means what.

The main problem to tackle is that the stream that such a socket provides has no notion of "messages". So when one party sends "HELLO", and "BYE" after that, it all gets concatenated into the stream: "HELLOBYE". Or worse even, your server first receives "HELL", followed by "OBYE".

So you need message framing, or rules how to interpret where messages start and end.

You generally don't want to invent your own application protocol. Usually HTTP or other existing protocols are leveraged to pass messages around.

Comment: so the server should execute tasks depending on the socket?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! This makes a lot more sense